# What shape do I need to have my array of color jpeg images in order to enter it into a CNN, and how do I reshape it to the required shape?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN with 20 jpeg images just as an exercise. I chose the shape of the input layer to be input_shape=(32, 32, 3) but I am getting errors. When I run a "print shape" for the image data array I get (10, ). I am not sure why it is like this. Shouldnt a color image shape have 3 or 4 dimensions? The shapes of my array of jpegs seems to be (10,)...one dimensional. How do I transform the shape in order to use the fit function below and to what shape?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

from matplotlib import pyplot
import random
import numpy as np

from os import listdir
from matplotlib import image
# load all the cat train images in the cat train directory
imagesWithLabels = []
for filename in listdir('C:/AI/images/airplanes'):
    # load image
    img_data = image.imread('C:/AI/images/airplanes/' +\
    filename)
    # store loaded image in a list
    imagesWithLabels.append((img_data,0))
    print('> loaded %s %s' % (filename, img_data.shape))

for filename in listdir('C:/AI/images/automobiles'):
    # load image
    img_data = image.imread('C:/AI/images/automobiles/' +\
     filename)
    # store loaded image in the list
    imagesWithLabels.append((img_data,1))
    print('> loaded %s %s' % (filename, img_data.shape))
    
#check to see that all 20 images of planes and autos are there    
len(imagesWithLabels)

random.shuffle(imagesWithLabels)

type(imagesWithLabels)

train = imagesWithLabels[:10]
test = imagesWithLabels[10:]
x_train, y_train = zip(*train)
x_test, y_test = zip(*test)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test)

y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

type(x_train)
type(x_test)

for i in range(10):
    pyplot.imshow(x_train[i] )
    pyplot.show()


CNN_model = models.Sequential()
CNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(50, (2, 2), activation='relu',\
input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
CNN_model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
CNN_model.add(layers.Flatten())
CNN_model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
CNN_model.add(layers.Dropout(.1))
CNN_model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = .005)
CNN_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
         (from_logits=False),metrics=['accuracy'])

history = CNN_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5,validation_data=( x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: After the first for loop, `imagesWithLabels` is a list of the ten images of planes, so its size is 10. You need to convert that to a tensor after the second for loop, use an operators such as `stack` or `concat`(sometimes `cat`).

Comment: Couldn't I just   use numpy's reshape function? I'm not sure how to use "stack" or "concat"

Comment: You are using TensorFlow, you should use its function (they are practically the same as Numpy, including a reshape method). The `stack` and `concat` functions, well, stack tensors stored in a Python list along a given dimension.

Comment: In your code `imagesWithLabels` is a list of 20 tensors (of shape `32x32x3` I guess), you can stack them in a new dimension to get a tensor of shape `20x32x32x3` for instance.

Comment: when i print the shape I get (10, ). How could color photos have 1 dimension ? I thought it would be dimensions for RGB. I have 10 color photos in the list. When I print  the list I do see what looks like a multidimensional array with 3 columns. But when I print the shape I get (10,). I guess I need to turn my list/array of 10 images into a tensor? But how do I do that specifically ? thanks

Comment: Should I use   image_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_data, dtype=tf.float32)

Comment: A Python list does not have a shape, only tensors have a shape. So yes, you should convert this list of tensors into one tensor of shape `(2, 32, 32, 3)`. Could you add a print statement `print(imagesWithLabels[0][0])` after the two for-loops to print the shape of the first image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the images are RGB images of the same size `(W, H, C) = (32, 32, 3)`, you can load them and store them in a Python list as you are doing (with labels). If you read 10 images, then this list is to length 10, and each item is a Numpy array or Tensor of shape `(32, 32, 3)`.

However, to train a network you must transform this list of Tensors into one Tensor. You achieve this by [stacking](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) the images along one new dimension:

```py
x_train, y_train = zip(*train)
x_test, y_test = zip(*test)

x_train = tf.stack(x_train)  
x_test = tf.stack(x_test)

y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)
y_test = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test)
```

Those tensors should be of size `(N, 32, 32, 3)` where `N` is the number of images in each set. Do not forget to transform everything into a Tensor before use in a network. You should use [`tf.convert_to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) which convert Python lists and Numpy arrays to Tensors.